# check script tag in a string using php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i want to check the script tag in an url

For example:
   if url have the script tag the below senario is working fine..

```
<?php
 $url = 'admin/content/test/<script>';
 preg_match('<script>', $url, $match);
 if (count($match) >= 1) {
  print 'It executes';
 }
?>
```

output:  `It executes`

but in my case if the url have a string "product_description" then also above condition matches

```
<?php
  $url = 'admin/content/product_description/test';
  preg_match('<script>', $url, $match);
  if (count($match) >= 1) {
   print 'It executes';
  }
?>
```

output: It executes

Please suggest the right way to check the script tag in an url..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `strpos`  instead of `preg_match`:

```
if (strpos($url,'<script>') !== false) {
   print 'It executes';
}
```

Here you have the manual of this function: [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: You are welcome. `preg_match` is sensible to special characters, when `strpos` isn't.

Comment: this does not work with `<script type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the regex inside delimiters:

```
preg_match('/<script>/', $url, $match);
```

You version worked because the pair `<>` were considered as delimiters, it was the same as:

```
preg_match('/script/', $url, $match);
```

and it matched `script` and also de`script`ion